# SharePoint 2010 workflow losing line breaks when copying to another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, multiline-text-field

I'm having some trouble with something I thought would be quite simple.

I was tasked with creating an InfoPath form attached to a document library that, when submitted, would extract some data from the form and create a new item in a custom list to enter the data into.

I have done this, my only problem being copying a multi-line text field to another multi-line text field. When creating the item in the list, all line breaks disappear, causing the data to be displayed on a single line. As this data can be quite large, this is a problem with the readability.

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious, but have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I knew it was going to be something simple.

The field I was copying from was a Rich Text field, while the field I was copying to was a Plain Text field.

All working as intended now.